# Polymer: What is the data-binding syntax attribute-name\$ for?

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I have come across some syntax I don't understand. The [docs for data binding in Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/data-binding) explain 2 different syntaxes for data bindings:

- One for binding to *properties*:
  `prop-name=...`
- And one for binding to *attributes* (e.g. `href`, `src`, `style` etc.):
  `attr-name$=...`

Trying to learn from source code of existing components I have come accross the construct `name\$=...` and I haven't found any documentation on what that is, so far.

In the [source for `<paper-input>`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/paper-input.js#L169) there is e.g. the following data binding for the `hidden` attribute on a `label` element:

```
<label hidden\$="[[!label]]" ... >[[label]]</label>
```

`hidden` is not even on the [list of properties, that require attribute binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#native-binding) (although that list may be incomplete). So I'm feeling really stuck (and confused) here.

Why is this `hidden\$=...` (i.e. with a backslash) and not just `hidden$=..."` (without the backslash) or `hidden=...` (without backslash and without dollar sign)? What does this syntax do? What is it used for?

Comment: The backslash is just an escape character (in this case is for $ which is not necessary I'm not sure why they use it). You can try paste `\`<label hidden\$="[[!label]]" ... >[[label]]</label>\`` in the console and see the result.

Comment: @user-28: Ah, of course! It's inside a template literal, d'oh! After reading the [MDN reference on template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), I think I also figured out, why they do it: In a template literal the `$` may start an expression interpolation (`${...}`), and the backslash prevents that. My guess is that a code generating tool created this artefact (just like some SQL generators always quote table and column names, whether necessary or not, just to be safe).

Answer (score 1):

A data binding appears in the local DOM template as an HTML attribute:

`property-name=annotation-or-compound-binding
   attribute-name$=annotation-or-compound-binding`

The left-hand side of the binding identifies the target property or attribute.

To bind to a property, use the property name in attribute form (dash-case not camelCase), as described in Property name to attribute name mapping:

`<my-element my-property="{{hostProperty}}">`

This example binds to the target property, myProperty on .

To bind to an attribute instead, use the attribute name followed by $:

`<a href$="{{hostProperty}}">`

This example binds to the anchor element's *href* **attribute**.

https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/data-binding